# Gradle: Spotless task not firing when needed

Tags: java, gradle, format, spotless

I followed the Spotless plugin's readme and included the following into my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

spotless {
    java {
        eclipseFormatFile 'my-eclipse-format.xml' 
    }
}
```

When I run "gradlew build", I expect Spotless to a) format my code automatically using the above format; b) do a check (ie spotlessJavaCheck) to verify it happened.

Instead, I only get the b) part working. How can I make sure a) (formatting) happens automatically when I execute the build step? I don't want to explicitly call "gradlew spotlessApply build" but only "gradlew build".

I tried adding "build { dependsOn spotlessApply } but it says "cannot find property spotlessApply".

Answer (score 8):

For future reference, [Spotless' GitHub issues](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues) is the best place to ask about Spotless.  Keeps it all in one place.

Spotless' intended behavior is to let you know that there's a problem with `spotlessCheck`.  Then you run `spotlessApply` yourself manually.

The problem with doing it the other way is that you'll never know about a bad commit.  If I commit badly formatted code, the CI server will fix the format with `spotlessApply`, then confirm the format is fixed in `spotlessCheck`, and say "this code is good!" when actually somebody committed something with wrong formatting.

If you still want what you want, you can accomplish it like this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName('spotlessCheck').dependsOn(tasks.getByName('spotlessApply'))
}
```

Comment: This was breaking way too often on completely trivial issues since some of the checks are very opinionated about e.g. new lines. Very disruptive to discover that CI failed over a newline. What matters is that this cleans itself up, eventually, provided you run gradle build locally once in a while. That is good enough. The end result is the same: clean code. I actually have intellij clean my code as well but it keeps the newlines.

Comment: Eventually consistent code formatting is good enough for me.